# sshpass want to use parameter of sftp

Tags: bash, sftp, sshpass

Hi i created following script to initialize my storage box to use rsync without password later. Last year it works if i remember correct...

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/storagebox_authorized_keys
echo -e "mkdir .ssh \n chmod 700 .ssh \n put $.ssh/storagebox_authorized_keys" \
    ".ssh/authorized_keys \n chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys" | sshpass -p ${storage_password} \
    sftp -P ${storage_port} -i .ssh/id_rsa ${storage_user}@${storage_address}
```

today I get following error:

> sshpass: invalid option -- 'i'

but the parameter -i belongs to sftp and not sshpass - is there an possibility to parse the parameters in the correct way?

edit: i switched the position of

```
-i .ssh/id_rsa ${storage_user}@${storage_address}
```

and get this error

> sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

edit: it seems like an sftp problem...

Comment: And do you need *both* the password and the key? If I understood correctly, you are logging in using *password* to setup key authentication with `.ssh/id_rsa`. So you do not need the `-i .ssh/id_rsa` for the `sftp` at this stage.

Comment: the process (init_script) (should) work without password. (automation of the server setup), passwords are stored in password-store. so i need to type my gpg passsphrase only once time after os installation and then I can go or have one or more coffees :P 

solution: -- in the sshpass command and the right order of parameters of sftp (sftp -P ... -i ... user@host)

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. What is the `-i .ssh/id_rsa` good for, if the server supposedly do not know the key yet?

Comment: haha you are right, its nonsense, thx ;) (didn't read your last sentence in the first comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after discussion, updating answer to properly support automation

#### step 1:

create an sftp "batch file" e.g: `~/.ssh/storage-box_setup.sftp`

```sh
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
put /path/to/authorized_keys_file ".ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

`/path/to/authorized_keys_file` is a file containing public keys of ONLY the keys that should have access to your storage box (`.ssh/storagebox_authorized_keys`)

#### step 2:

update automation script command to

```sh
sshpass -p <password> -- sftp -P <port> -b ~/.ssh/storage-box_setup.sftp user@host
```

the `-b` flag was the answer you needed.
refer: [`man sftp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp#:%7E:text=is%2032768%20bytes.-,%2Db%20batchfile,-Batch%20mode%20reads)

> -b batchfile
>
> Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input batchfile instead of stdin. Since it lacks user interaction it should be used in conjunction with non-interactive authentication.

---

#### `--`

```
sshpass -p ${storage_password} -- \
    sftp -P ${storage_port} -i .ssh/id_rsa \ 
    ${storage_user}@${storage_address}
```

the `--` before `sftp` is a way to tell `sshpass` (and most other programs) to stop *parsing* arguments.

everything after `--` is assumed as the last argument, which in the case of `sshpass` is the command to be executed `ssh -i ~/.id_rsa ...`

---

in case you're wondering switching the position of `-i` tells sshpass to execute `-i` as a program and hence fails with command not found

Comment: nonetheless i have no idea what the rest of your command is doing :) it doesn't seem necessary, but i may be wrong.

Comment: you mean the echo? it should "upload" the ssh-key to the storage box. i followed this guide (penultimate box): https://docs.hetzner.com/de/robot/storage-box/backup-space-ssh-keys/

Comment: es bin auf Deutsch! :( mein Deutsch ist nicht gut. but from what i can tell, that's supposed to be the command for sftp, not sshpass. does your sshkey `~/.ssh/id_rsa` have a passpharse?

Comment: Es ist auf Deutsch, yes ;) (translate.google.com) but not important. b2t: I have no passphrase, i want to create the ssh-key via sftp without passwordprompt on the storage box. But now if i use sshpass in my command, it will say: "Permission denied, please try again." if i remove the sshpass part, then it deploy the ssh-key correct. but he asks me for an password... but all my passwords are saved in .password-store to automate my scripts which contain or need a password

Comment: so the echo is used to create the ssh key "things" on the storage box, but i have to enter a password
sshpass is used to bypass the password prompt but now I am getting a "permission denied" error (after your adaption with "--")
The script itself only runs once after server setup, but I love automatic processes and I want to use sshpass for that D: (my files (in the storagebox) are encrypted by gpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240753/discussion-between-ted-mosby-and-kevinnls).